# TYPO3: Sorting in Backend for items in SysFolders

Tags: sorting, typo3, backend, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I've the following problem: in my TYPO3 backend (TYPO3 8.7.24) I've got multiple SysFoldern for my tt_products items (just to arrange everything a bit). But in the list view the sorting arrows are missing.

[TYPO3-Backend-Sorting_ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soo4V.png)
TYPO3 was setup freshly in the version 8. For tt_products (v 2.9.4) I'm using the followig addition in the template.
plugin.tt_products.conf.tt_products.LIST.orderBy = sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow manual sorting of products in the backend with TypoScript, but it is slightly different:

```
plugin.tt_products.conf.tt_products.orderBy = sorting
```

Answer (score 0):

`plugin.tt_products.conf.tt_products.LIST.orderBy = sorting` works in frontend only. In the Backend sorting of the products is [hard-coded](https://github.com/franzholz/tt_products/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tt_products.php#L27) to be by title. If you want to change it, you would need to adjust table definition (`$TCA`) with another extension.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Okay and this fixed sorting is the reason why the arrow buttons to adopt the field "sorting" are not visible?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure tt_products in the backend settings (previously in the extension manager).

```
Order tables by sorting
basic.orderBySortingTables (string)
```

Enter this:

```
tt_products,tt_products_language
```

This will enable the sorting arrows in the backend list module.